Extracting full sentences from PDF documents using key phrases
I want to extract sentences which include the word "emission" from a PDF document. It is a sustainability reports and therefore has different layouts, like tables, different structured paragraphs etc. However, I don't seem to be getting the full sentences extracted.
import pdfplumber
import pandas as pd

# Funktion: Text und Tabellen aus PDF extrahieren
def extract_text_and_tables(pdf_path):
    extracted_data = []
    with pdfplumber.open(pdf_path) as pdf:
        for page in pdf.pages:
            # Extrahiere Fließtext
            page_text = page.extract_text()
            
            # Extrahiere Tabellen
            tables = page.extract_tables()
            extracted_data.append({"text": page_text, "tables": tables})
    return extracted_data

# Funktion: Statements mit "emissions" extrahieren
def extract_emissions_statements(data):
    emissions_statements = []

    for page_data in data:
        # Text durchsuchen
        if page_data["text"]:
            for line in page_data["text"].splitlines():
                if "emission" in line.lower():
                    emissions_statements.append({"type": "text", "content": line.strip()})

        # Tabellen durchsuchen
        for table in page_data["tables"]:
            if table:  # Falls Tabelle existiert
                for row in table:
                    # Überprüfe, ob "emission" in der Tabellenzeile vorkommt
                    if any("emission" in str(cell).lower() for cell in row):
                        emissions_statements.append({"type": "table_row", "content": row})
    return emissions_statements

# Funktion: Ergebnisse formatieren
def format_emissions_statements(statements):
    formatted = []
    for statement in statements:
        if statement["type"] == "text":
            formatted.append(statement["content"])
        elif statement["type"] == "table_row":
            formatted.append(" | ".join(str(cell) for cell in statement["content"]))
    return formatted

# PDF-Dateipfad
pdf_path = "dein_report.pdf"

# Schritt 1: PDF-Text und Tabellen extrahieren
extracted_data = extract_text_and_tables(pdf_path)

# Schritt 2: Statements mit "emissions" extrahieren
emissions_statements = extract_emissions_statements(extracted_data)

# Schritt 3: Statements formatieren
formatted_statements = format_emissions_statements(emissions_statements)

# Ergebnisse anzeigen
for idx, statement in enumerate(formatted_statements):
    print(f"Statement {idx+1}: {statement}")

# Optional: Ergebnisse in eine CSV-Datei speichern
df = pd.DataFrame({"Statements": formatted_statements})
df.to_csv("emissions_statements.csv", index=False)

I tried the code above, but my output looks like this:

Statement 13: Energy and Emissions:
Statement 14: transition to Net Zero and compensation for residual emissions with
Statement 15:  Reducing the Energy and Emission Intensity per Rupee of Turnover.
Statement 16:  Emission Intensity (MtCO2e per Rupee of Turnover): Achieved a
Statement 17: last year, the Emission intensity has reduced by 26%. 

For example, in statements 14 and 17, it is evident that the full sentence wasn't extracted. How can I change this to get the whole sentences?

You don't need to split the text by '\n' if you want to split it in sentences. On the contrary, you have to concatenate text on all pages and then apply either re, or nltk, or spacy, etc. See answers to the general question here, or here with spacy. Also, you may find these discussions useful: one, two, three
